# creating view in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to create `View` in `MVC` programmatically through c# and want to place it in a `View folder` in my `MVC project`. If this is possible then please tell me how can i implement such logic?

Comment: Can you explain why do you need this?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Programmatically he said...

Comment: @HenkHolterman OP wants to create it programatically

Comment: Thanks @HenkHolterman but i want to add it through c# as i mentioned in my question

Comment: Right, comment deleted. Does not make much more sense though.

Comment: @user1400722 are you trying to implement some sort of CMS?

Comment: A view is a text file, just with a different extension. Is there some sort of protection in MVC preventing you from creating a file in the desired location? Or you didn't even try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement IView interface and build your own view:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public class MyCustomView : IView
    {
        public void Render(ViewContext viewContext, System.IO.TextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("view's content");
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyCustomView());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume it would be possible to just write the file and save it in the views folder programatically (assuming write permissions are granted). But you would also need an action you pass the name of view:

```
public ActionResult ShowProgramaticView(string nameOfTheView){
    return this.View(nameOfTheView);
}
```

Depending on your structure, you could write the file to the shared folder or the sub folder for this controller.